# Java zk hierarchy fetch database

Tags: java, zk

I have problem for fetching my data to view tree first I fetch data from service impl and i have .zul in view how to I fetch data from service imp to .zul in view.

this is the controller

```
package id.co.fifgroup.ims.controller;

import java.util.List;

import id.co.fifgroup.core.service.SecurityService;
import id.co.fifgroup.ims.domain.Violence;
import id.co.fifgroup.ims.service.ViolenceService;

import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.select.annotation.Wire;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.select.annotation.WireVariable;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.util.GenericForwardComposer;
import org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.SpringUtil;
import org.zkoss.zul.ListModel;
import org.zkoss.zul.ListModelList;
import org.zkoss.zul.Window;

public class ViolenceInquiryComposer extends GenericForwardComposer<Component> {

    @Wire
    private Violence violence;

    @Wire
    private Window winViolenceInquiry;

    @WireVariable(rewireOnActivate = true)
    private transient ViolenceService violenceServiceImpl = (ViolenceService) SpringUtil.getBean("violenceServiceImpl");;

    @Override
    public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {
        super.doAfterCompose(comp);
        initParentViolence();
    }

    public ListModel<Violence> initParentViolence(){
        Violence violence = new Violence();
        return new ListModelList<Violence>(violenceServiceImpl.getViolence(1));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to ZK framework.

I can see you don't have a lot of experience in the framework, so let's start.
First of all, ZK has 3 different implementations :

- MVC, in the swing way.
- MVC, with Composers.
- MVVM.

So, the first thing is to choose the way you want to go.
As with this setup, looks like you want MVC with Composers, so let's start there :

```
@Wire
private Violence violence;
```

If `Violence` doesn't extend or implement any ZK component, this is just plain wrong.
The `@Wire` stands for wiring your zul component to this class.

```
@Wire
private Window winViolenceInquiry;
```

This is correct, as long your window has the `id="winViolenceInquiry"`.
You see, I have a component in the zul => I make a connection to this class with `@Wire`.

Now you should have a specific component in the zul like a grid, listbox or tree.
Nothing will happen, as long you don't apply your `ListModelList` to that component.
So the first step, is declaring the component in the zul.
Then we make the connection in the java class with `@Wire`.
And as last step, in the `doAfterCompose` we do :

```
@Override
public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {
    super.doAfterCompose(comp);
    myList.setModel(initParentViolence());
}
```

Don't forget to add a renderer or use a template tag in the zul, in order to know how to render it correctly.

Now some advanced points :

1. Always try to make your ListModelList as a global final variable.
   The reason is very simple, as long you use this model : changes are done with ajax calls who only has the change in it, setting a new ListModelList will remove all the rendered items and append all the new items again, so long ajax calls and heavier for client pc to render.
2. I suggest you check out MVVM, as this is a very easy and fast way to code, and the learning curve is faster then MVC.
3. Try to use `SelectorComposer` in stead of `GenericForwardComposer` because the last one is an "older" version, and you could make more mistakes there.
   `SelectorComposer` also supports CSS3-selector in order do wire your components.